# Multiple DN suffixes in openLDAP

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to create multiple dn suffixes with openLDAP, but it doesn't seem to work.

I want have this:

```
ou=Jamaika,dc=gov,dc=com
ou=Jamaiks-shadow,dc=gov-shadow,dc=com-shadow
```

Should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akw2O.jpg

I can create dc=com, but not dc=com-shadow.

```
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

---

I cannot query `cn=config` using the rootDN from a different suffix:

```
/products/openldap-2.4.40/bin/ldapsearch -h xxxx -p xxxx -D cn=admin,dc=com -b cn=config -W
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF

# LDAPv3
# base <cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object
# numResponses: 1
```

---

**SLAPD.CONF**

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=com"
rootpw          ....
directory       /products/openldap-2.4.40/var/openldap-data
loglevel 64
index   objectClass     eq
access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="dc=com" by * read
```

But I don't want to have this:

**SLAPD.CONF**

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=com"
rootpw          ....
directory       /products/openldap-2.4.40/var/openldap-data
loglevel 64
index   objectClass     eq
access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="dc=com" by * read

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=com-shadow"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=com-shadow"
rootpw          ....
directory       /products/openldap-2.4.40/var/openldap-data
loglevel 64
index   objectClass     eq
access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="dc=com" by * read
```

because then I have two users for one LDAP-System.

Comment: Did you add configuration for the second tree to `cn=config`?

Comment: Hmmm how does it work, i didn't find any documentation. :(

Comment: Yes you did, that's how you defined the first tree. It's another database.

Comment: I defined it with suffix="" , so no it is possible to add more dc=...